# Wrong generic overload function called

Tags: ios, swift, generics, subtyping

I'm trying to understand why the where clause of a generic method is ignored

I've made a simple use case in Swift 3 (you can copy the code in a playground if you wanna fiddle with it):

```
//MARK: - Classes

protocol HasChildren {
    var children:[Human] {get}
}

class Human {}

class SeniorHuman : Human, HasChildren {
    var children: [Human] {
        return [AdultHuman(), AdultHuman()]
    }
}

class AdultHuman : Human, HasChildren {
    var children: [Human] {
        return [YoungHuman(), YoungHuman(), YoungHuman()]
    }
}

class YoungHuman : Human {}

//MARK: - Generic Methods

/// This method should only be called for YoungHuman
func sayHelloToFamily<T: Human>(of human:T) {
    print("Hello \(human). You have no children. But do you conform to protocol? \(human is HasChildren)")
}

/// This method should be called for SeniorHuman and AdultHuman, but not for YoungHuman...
func sayHelloToFamily<T: Human>(of human:T) where T: HasChildren {
    print("Hello \(human). You have \(human.children.count) children, good for you!")
}
```

Ok, so now let's run some tests. If we have :

```
let senior = SeniorHuman()
let adult = AdultHuman()

print("Test #1")
sayHelloToFamily(of: senior)

print("Test #2")
sayHelloToFamily(of: adult)

if let seniorFirstChildren = senior.children.first {
    print("Test #3")
    sayHelloToFamily(of: seniorFirstChildren)

    print("Test #4")
    sayHelloToFamily(of: seniorFirstChildren as! AdultHuman)
}
```

The output is:

```
Test #1
Hello SeniorHuman. You have 2 children, good for you!

Test #2
Hello AdultHuman. You have 3 children, good for you!

Test #3
Hello AdultHuman. You have no children. But do you conform to protocol? true
//Well, why are you not calling the other method then?

Test #4
Hello AdultHuman. You have 3 children, good for you!
//Oh... it's working here... It seems that I just can't use supertyping
```

Well... apparently, for the `where` protocol clause to work, we need to pass a strong type that conforms to the protocol in its definition.

Just using supertyping is not enough, even if it is obvious in the test #3 that the given instance is actually conforming to the `HasChildren` protocol.

**So, what am I missing here, is this just not possible?** Do you have some links giving more information about what's going on, or more information about `where` clauses, or subtyping and its behavior in general?

I've read a few useful resources but none seems to have an exhaustive explanation about why it's not working:

- [Type Variance in Swift](https://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift)
- [Covariance and Contravariance](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html)
- [Which function does Swift call](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/10/26/which-function-does-swift-call-part-4-generics/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the method to be called is selected during compile time. What does the compiler know about your types?

```
if let seniorFirstChildren = senior.children.first {
```

`seniorFirstChildren` is `Human` because that's how `children` are declared. We have no information whether the `child` is adult or senior.

However, consider this:

```
if let seniorFirstChildren = senior.children.first as? AdultHuman {
```

Now the compiler knows `seniorFirstChildren` is `AdultHuman` and it will call the method you expect.

You have to distinguish between *static types* (types known during compilation) and *dynamic types* (types known at runtime).

Comment: Well, it is pretty obvious when you say it like this. Can't believe I missed that... I guess my idea of recursive generic functions would not work properly then, if we cannot make them dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

From [the Language Guide - Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html):

> **Checking Type**
>
> Use the type check operator (`is`) to check whether an instance is of
>   a certain subclass type. The type check operator returns `true` if the
>   instance is of that subclass type and `false` if it is not.

The type check operator `is` is resolved at *runtime*, whereas the overload resolution of the call to `sayHelloToFamily` using the first `children` member of your instance of `AdultHuman` (binded to `seniorFirstChildren`) as argument is resolved at *compile time* (in which case it's typed as `Human`, which does not conform to `HasChildren`). If you explicitly tell the compiler that `seniorFirstChildren` is an `AdultHuman` instance (using the unsafe `as! AdultHuman`), then naturally the compiler will make use of this information to choose the more specific overload.